# how to know which option was clicked without using an id on the option element

Tags: javascript

I need to be able to know what option is being clicked on, I have used

```
    let selection = document.getElementById("list");
```

but this only works when I click on the list as a whole, I have tried getting all the options but I only can see what is inside

```
    let opt = document.getElementsByTagName("option");
```

I need to be able to catch the option that was clicked so I can send a message depending on the one chosen!
Also, I can not use values on the option tag.

```
<select id="list">
        <option>Select a Currency</option>
        <option>UK Pounds</option>
        <option>Euros</option>
        <option>Yen</option>
        <option>Yuan</option>
        <option>Swiss Francs</option>
        <option>Canadian Dollars</option>
</select>
<p id="exchangerate"></p>
```

then i need to target the id "exchangerate" and write there what rate according to the option selected

Comment: people typically use value...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Comment: I know, using the value it's much easier but I was told I can't use so I have no idea how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Add a function to the `onchange` event.

```
<select id="list" onchange="alert(this.value)">
    <option>Select a Currency</option>
    <option>UK Pounds</option>
    <option>Euros</option>
    <option>Yen</option>
    <option>Yuan</option>
    <option>Swiss Francs</option>
    <option>Canadian Dollars</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I cant modify the html at all

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `EventHandler` to `change` event of the `list`, then catch the `value` or `text` of selected option.

```js
document.getElementById("list").addEventListener("change", function(e){
  
  document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
  
  //-------------------------------------------------
  document.getElementById("exchangerate").innerHTML = this.value;
  //OR  
  document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
  
});
```

```html
<select id="list">
        <option>Select a Currency</option>
        <option value="1">UK Pounds</option>
        <option value="2">Euros</option>
        <option value="3">Yen</option>
        <option value="4">Yuan</option>
        <option value="5">Swiss Francs</option>
        <option value="6">Canadian Dollars</option>
</select>
<br><br><br>
Selected Text: <span id="a"></span><br>
Selected Value: <span id="b"></span><br>
Selected Value: <span id="c"></span><br>
```

**If you can not change the HTML, use this code:**

```js
document.getElementById("list").addEventListener("change", function(e){
  document.getElementById("exchangerate").innerHTML = this.value;  
});
```

```html
<select id="list">
        <option>Select a Currency</option>
        <option>UK Pounds</option>
        <option>Euros</option>
        <option>Yen</option>
        <option>Yuan</option>
        <option>Swiss Francs</option>
        <option>Canadian Dollars</option>
</select>
<p id="exchangerate"></p>
```

Comment: it´s a great way but I cant add anything to the HTML at all

Comment: If your options have not `value` (if you can not add anything to the HTML) then easily use `document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = this.value;` inside the above `function` to get `text` of the selected item. I means  `this.value` will return `text` of selected item if you don't set value for the options.

Comment: what ("b") would be that?

Comment: Look at my code. I wrote `<span id="b"></span>`. You have `<p id="exchangerate"></p>` in your code. Then `b` is equal to `exchangerate`. Use 'exchangerate' instead of 'b'.

Comment: I wish I could add anything to the original HTML

Comment: @juangomez, I added another sample to my answer. Look at the answer, you do not need add anything to the original HTML. Just use my answer and inside its `function` use `document.getElementById("exchangerate").innerHTML = this.value;`